# Maximize objective function in R

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to find max value (response) given the size of difference (independent variables).

Here is some data:

```
 x <- "A B C 
 1  0.63 0.67 0.61
 2  0.62 0.64 0.60
 3  0.64 0.65 0.59
 4  0.70 0.70 0.63
 5  0.71 0.73 0.68
 6  0.70 0.75 0.69
 7  0.71 0.75 0.70
 8  0.74 0.76 0.71
 9  0.79 0.81 0.74
10 0.80 0.83 0.76
11 0.82 0.84 0.78
12 0.82 0.84 0.80
13 0.83 0.85 0.81
14 0.81 0.88 0.80
15 0.78 0.84 0.77
16 0.75 0.79 0.74
17 0.73 0.77 0.72
18 0.72 0.75 0.71
19 0.73 0.75 0.71
20 0.73 0.75 0.71
21 0.74 0.76 0.72
22 0.72 0.76 0.71
23 0.71 0.74 0.69
24 0.73 0.75 0.70
25 0.78 0.79 0.71
26 0.82 0.84 0.77
27 0.80 0.84 0.78
28 0.77 0.81 0.76
29 0.79 0.81 0.75
30 0.83 0.84 0.78
31 0.86 0.87 0.82
32 0.85 0.87 0.83
33 0.83 0.84 0.82
34 0.78 0.85 0.77
35 0.74 0.80 0.72
36 0.72 0.76 0.71
37 0.74 0.77 0.70
38 0.75 0.75 0.70
39 0.78 0.81 0.72
40 0.78 0.82 0.75" 

# Or generate it like this
x <- data.frame(
  A = c(0.63, 0.62, 0.64, 0.7, 0.71, 0.7, 0.71, 0.74, 0.79, 0.8, 0.82, 0.82, 0.83, 0.81, 0.78, 0.75, 0.73, 0.72, 0.73, 0.73, 0.74, 0.72, 0.71, 0.73, 0.78, 0.82, 0.8, 0.77, 0.79, 0.83, 0.86, 0.85, 0.83, 0.78, 0.74, 0.72, 0.74, 0.75, 0.78, 0.78),
  B = c(0.67, 0.64, 0.65, 0.7, 0.73, 0.75, 0.75, 0.76, 0.81, 0.83, 0.84, 0.84, 0.85, 0.88, 0.84, 0.79, 0.77, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.76, 0.76, 0.74, 0.75, 0.79, 0.84, 0.84, 0.81, 0.81, 0.84, 0.87, 0.87, 0.84, 0.85, 0.8, 0.76, 0.77, 0.75, 0.81, 0.82),
  C = c(0.61, 0.6, 0.59, 0.63, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7, 0.71, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 0.8, 0.81, 0.8, 0.77, 0.74, 0.72, 0.71, 0.71, 0.71, 0.72, 0.71, 0.69, 0.7, 0.71, 0.77, 0.78, 0.76, 0.75, 0.78, 0.82, 0.83, 0.82, 0.77, 0.72, 0.71, 0.7, 0.7, 0.72, 0.75))
```

And here some adjustment:

```
data <- read.table(text=x, header = TRUE)

data$diff_AC <- with(data, (A-C))
data$diff_AB <- with(data, (A-B))

with(data, plot(A~1, col=1))
with(data, points(B~1, col=2))
with(data, points(C~1, col=3))
```

Calculate return:

```
data$retA <- with(data, as.numeric(c(0,diff(A))/lag(A,1)))
```

Now using `optim` find the size of difference of A vs B and A vs C at which the return of A (`retA`) is highest given all data of A.

`This should be done separately for negative return and positive return`.

I have tried this, but I'm not sure how to bring in the `return A` part into `optim`.

```
max.rss <- function(data, par) { with(data, -sum((par[1] * (B - A) + (C - A))^2)) }
result <- optim(par = 0, max.rss, data = data, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1)
```

**EDIT:**

So the question is at which level (the size of difference) `diff_AB` and `diff_AC` should be so that the `retA` (return of series `A`) is highest (maximised) and what is the difference size `diff_AB` and `diff_AC` at which the `retA` is at its minimum (the highest negative rate).

```
with(data, plot(retA ~ diff_AB, ylim=c(-0.1,0.1), xlim=c(-.1,.1)))
with(data, points(retA ~ diff_AC, col="red3"))
```

**EDIT2:**

It's very likely that the question is not well defined, or with current explanation it does not necessarily makes sense.

**Any proposition towards analysis/modeling the underlying dynamics is welcome!**

**EDIT 3:**

Here is possible solution somewhat based on existing answer:

```
data$rank_min <- with(data, ave(retA, diff_AB, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method="min")))
data$rank_max <- with(data, ave(retA, diff_AB, FUN=function(x) rank(x, ties.method="max")))

with(data, data[rank_min==min(rank_min), ])
with(data, data[rank_max==max(rank_max), ])
```

or (but I'm not sure whether this is fully correct)

```
diff_binAB <- with(data, unique(diff_AB))
mse <- numeric(length(diff_binAB))

for(i in 1:length(diff_binAB)){
pwise <- with(data, lm(retA ~ diff_AB*(diff_AB < diff_binAB[i]) + diff_AB*(diff_AB >= diff_binAB[i])))
mse[i] <- summary(pwise)[6]
}

mse <- as.numeric(mse)
mse 

diff_binAB[which(mse==min(mse))]
# -0.07
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but notice that the objective "maximize return of A" is constant as A is data. You probably should write things down in terms of a mathematical model where it is clear what the decision variables are.

Comment: Hm, well, I'm not sure, I just want to determine the size of the difference 'A vs. B` when the return of A `(retA)` is highest. (one could just take `data[which.max(retA), ]` and check the columns of the difference `A vs. B` and `A vs. C`. But this would be determine based on 1 observation, which I don't want. I want to estimate is based on all information.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, and possibly what you're thinking isn't clear either.  From your example, what is the desired output?

Comment: the expected output is size of difference betweenA vs. B and A vs. C that would lead to predicting greater change retA. So basically, I'm expecting that if I observe increasing difference between A vs. B that approaches the estimated threshold (difference A vs. B) I will at the same time or in due course observe the highest rate of change of A or rather greater likelihood of observing positive increase (or negative difference for negative decrease). Does it makes sense?

Comment: It really does not make sense. Wouldn't the highest rate of change be given by `retaA/diff_AB` ?

Comment: by rate of change, I mean `retA`, it could be that the lowest size of `diff_AB` produces highest `retA`...so no the ratio proposed by you is not the solution I'm looking for...

Comment: Are these data meant to be a sample? Are we estimating a model where `retA` depends on `diffA` and `diffB`?

Comment: yes, the data is a subset of a larger sample. No, `retA` is a results of series of variable `A` and the variables `B` and `C` are different variables, however clearly dependent (correlated). `diff_AB` is the difference between variables `A` and `B` so yes, diff_AB depends (partly) on `A`.

Comment: It would help if you provide the backgroung and your hypotheses behind the data. Are these stock prices? It seems like you assume something like that returns on A are dependent on its spread to B and C...? In any case, it does not seem to be a case for numerical optimization other than fitting some model. Also if these are time series, you should definitely take it into account or you can get spurious results. See my answer.

Comment: No, these are not stock prices. These are moving average (window 20 days) of probabilities (observing a particular number of species in given time) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on a single observation (like with `data[which.max(retA), ]`) you can either use 10% quantiles :

```
with(data, summary(diff_AB[retA < quantile(data$retA, 0.1)]))
with(data, summary(diff_AC[retA < quantile(data$retA, 0.1)]))

with(data, summary(diff_AB[retA > quantile(data$retA, 0.9)]))
with(data, summary(diff_AC[retA > quantile(data$retA, 0.9)]))
```

or estimate a model of the dependence

```
m1 <- with(data, lm(retA~diff_AC+diff_AB))
summary(m1)

m2 <- with(data, lm(retA ~ I(diff_AC+diff_AB)))
summary(m2)
```

But you might want to account for the autocorrelation of your time-series residuals:

```
plot(m2$residuals, type = "l")
```

[image: linear model]

For example, let's assume it is an AR(1) process:

```
library(astsa)

m3 <- with(data, sarima(retA, 1,0,0, xreg=cbind(diff_AB, diff_AC)))
```

[image: linear model with AR(1) errors]

and then predict `retA` based on this model.

Comment: Hi, I'm accepting your answer as no one else provided answer. My expectation was that someone provided some nice modelling approach but this didn't happen. It is certainly my fault as I failed to better describe the needs in timely manner (provided late updates to this question). Thanks.